# Case with result set in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I want's to test following query in mysql

```
SELECT result.* FROM 
(CASE WHEN (2 = 2) 
THEN
(SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE myID =2814 )
END) result ;
```

but it is sending syntax error.
Any idea what's wrong with it ?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? You don't need the case statement for the query above.

Comment: What i will do is on different cases i will return different resultset from different tables.
First I just wanted to test whether i could return result set on bases of case or not.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in a round about way like so

```
SET @query := NULL;

SELECT @query := t.qry 
FROM 
(   SELECT 
        CASE WHEN 2 = 2
             THEN "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE myID =2814"
             WHEN another_condition
             THEN "another_select"
        END as qry
) t ;

PREPARE query1 FROM @query;
EXECUTE query1;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

Obviously, your query is equivalent to:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE myID = 2814;
```

This makes it a bit hard to figure out what you are asking.

Fundamentally, though `case` is an expression, and the `from` clause does not accept expressions.  It accepts table names, view names, subqueries, and the like.  Second, the `case` statement has a few other problems.

- It returns a scalar scalar value.  The subquery could return more than one row.
- Returning more than one column is not allowed
- All the clauses need to return the same thing

If you wanted to select from multiple tables -- and all of them have the same structure -- you can use a `union all` construct:

```
select t.*
from table2 t
where . . .
union all
select t.*
from table2 t
where . . .
```

Comment: it is just a sample my real query will be different in different cases

Comment: @KamranShahid . . . Perhaps you should ask another question that provides enough detail to provide a useful answer (unless the dynamic SQL suggested by John works for you).  Don't edit this question -- it is unfair to those of us who have answered it in its current form.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to use a different query each time (which at least will allow mysql some chance of using indexes properly).

However assuming there are several sub queries that you want as a source for data depending on the check then maybe something like this:-

```
SELECT result.* 
FROM 
(
    SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE 2 = 2 AND myID = 2814  
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM mytable2 WHERE 1 = 2 AND myID = 2814  
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM mytable3 WHERE 3 = 2 AND myID = 2814  
) result ;
```

Comment: the issue with this is it seems like the OP only wants to execute a particular query and this could cause run time issues

Comment: Fully agree, but that is what you would dynamically build sql to do. This solution will work in the way he currently wants, and given that most of the unioned queries will bring back nothing that should be relatively efficient. Down side is any where clause used once on the results of the sub query will not use any indexes.